# Expected 2 arguments, but got 0. i have this error in custom Directive

Tags: angular

this is angular using custom Directive:(TemplateRef,ViewContainerRef)
import { TimesDirective } from './times.directive';

describe(' TimesDirective ', () => {
it('should create an instance', () => {
const directive = new `TimesDirective` ();
expect(directive).`toBeTruthy`();
});
});````` your text````your text `````
this is code.
and this is error:Expected 2 arguments, but got 0. i have this error in custom Directive.
how to solve this error

find solution. and provide solution for this

Comment: "find solution. and provide solution for this" this is not chatgpt. there are real people spending their free time here.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom directive you have created a method in which you defined 2 arguments, but when you're calling that directive from your component, you're passing 0 arguments.